# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection First connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, design-patterns, connection-pooling

I have this problem. I've googled a lot of sites with this issue, but all of them advice to close all  the connection, or just using "using" with connection and dataReader. BUT! My probles is in that I can't open the first connection! I set a breakpoint near connection, and saw, that there are no others connections, so, there is a first one. This problem rized when I remake the class which open connection from static to Singleton, here is the code:

```
public class Storage
{
private static Storage instance;

public static Storage Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Storage();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

private Storage()
{
    Manager man = new Manager();
    products = man.LoadProducts();
    components = man.LoadComponents();
    man.LoadProductComponents();
}

public Dictionary<int, Product> Products
    {
        get { return products; }
        set { products = value; }
    }

public Dictionary<int, Component> Components
    {
        get { return components; }
        set { components = value; }
    }

private Dictionary<int, Product> products;
private Dictionary<int, Component> components;

}
```

and here is a Manager constructor

```
    public Manager()
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Password=pass;Initial Catalog=Products;Server=(local)");
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) connection.Open();
    }
```

When exception raises, the connection is `Closed`. Any one have ideas?

**UPDATE:**

if I turn off pooling - I have `"System.StackOverflowException" in System.Data.dll` at the same line.

Comment: Personally I'd say that anything that involves a connection fixed in a singleton is inherently a bad idea. But: how many other places are there that load managers? in particular, anything that spins up a few managers will have the side effect of locking up connections with no hope of them closing.

Comment: The problem is in first connection, so the Manager() in one. I tried to make Singleton with lock() but it doesn't help.

Comment: and is this the only connection / manager instance in the *entire application*? Does the message end with "from the pool"?

Comment: @MarcGravell Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Comment: If I make Manager and Storage just static - all works fine.

Comment: then you are going to have to do some debugging. The connection pool can't see your code: it is doing the same thing. The only thing that is changing here is *your code*. So the problem, in 99% of cases, is going to be with *your code*. In particular, I would be putting break-points or trace-points in any code that creates or opens a connection. You might be surprised by different code-paths that get you there.

Comment: @MarcGravell I putted breakpoints, and start debuggin, and the problem is in the first connection, when I try to Open() connection - the state is Closed.

Comment: I've tested your code in my project. Everything works properly in singletone version. Check your connection settings

Comment: I would be searching my entire code-base for `Connection`, and putting a breakpoint on *anything* that creates/opens a connection... the code you have shown, while not ideal, should at least *work*, but I'm worried in particular about how many `Manager` instances are being created - we can't tell that from your code. I'll demonstrate my concerns in an answer...

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok, i maded Manager static, and make method connect where Oepn() connection. I call it once (I'm sure). But problem is the same

Comment: You have private constructor and the member "instance" inside your class is static. That means you can't create instance of your storage class. What and where is your application's starting point?

Comment: Well you simply cannot connect to the DB server, other coding problems aside.  Are you sure SQL Server is running at a default instance (no \SQLEXPRESS or \INSTANCENAME etc) and has mixed-mode authentication turned on?

Comment: @Umesh http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: @KierenJohnstone with connection string all Ok, it works if storage just static, not Singleton

Comment: Then I'm afraid you are mistaken and it's not the first connection that fails, but subsequent ones, and you need to start taking Marc's advice

Comment: Problem was in looping, man.LoadProductComponents() tried to get Storage.Insance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Manager` class creates and opens a connection:

```
public Manager()
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Password=pass;Initial Catalog=Products;Server=(local)");
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) connection.Open();
}
```

However, if we look at how you are using it, it is clear that nothing is ever *closing* this connection:

```
private Storage()
{
    Manager man = new Manager();
    products = man.LoadProducts();
    components = man.LoadComponents();
    man.LoadProductComponents();
}
```

I would expect `Manager` to implement `IDisposable`, and have the `Dispose()` method close and release the connection:

```
class Manager : IDisposable
{
    ...
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(connection != null) connection.Dispose();
        connection = null;
    }
}
```

which would then be used via `using`:

```
private Storage()
{
    using(Manager man = new Manager())
    {
        products = man.LoadProducts();
        components = man.LoadComponents();
        man.LoadProductComponents();
    }
}
```

My concern is that your manager is just a single example of a wider problem: of not cleaning up connections after yourself. When the `Manager` is static, this is probably quite invisible, but when switching to `Manager` instances, it would be easy to be spinning up multiple `Manager` objects. Each of this ties up a connection until GC.

Comment: I said, that i can see, when exception is raizes the state of connection is Closed. So, how your Dispose() can help me? It is the first connection, I just can't connect at the first time.

Comment: @user1947702 how to put this... that particular error message doesn't happen for a first connection. It happens when you have saturated the pool by not cleaning up connections. And you have posted code that doesn't clean up the connection. I am very suspicious that there are other connections being created, maybe elsewhere in the code, that is saturating the pool.